MVC application with Microservices architecture
I have hardly worked on MVC. Can anyone help me with MVC application with microservices architecture.? or any youtube videos that could be referred here? I will go through them. I know This platform is not meant for these questions. But I genuinely seek help here. I want to learn MVC with microservices architecture. I have got a new requirment where we should use MVC with microservices architecture. Thanks in adv.

Alex Hyett has a solid series of videos on YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/@alexhyettdev
I'm not sure if he's covered MVC specifically but he has covered Microservices vs Monoliths.  Personally I've never had to deal much with MVC specifically.
More broadly, as you start to move into thinking about solution design and architecture, you need to develop good research skills.
I understand that there are many people blogging and vlogging on various software design patterns, technologies and so on, and that the quality level of that material is super variable (some of it is good, some mediocre, and some awful) - so it can be onerous to sift through it all and know who is giving good advice.  Unfortunately that's part of being good at researching: learning how to identify good sources, how to cross-check ideas from different sources and come up with distillations that make sense to you and what you are doing, and so on.
If you trust Stackoverflow (SO) as a source, you could start by doing a search in SO for questions tagged with MVC and Architecture
